# How do I stop Strings with an ebedded vbCrLf placed in MyLabel.Text from adding a blank line when converted to a library .DLL

Tags: string, vb.net, dll, label

I wrote a replacement for VB's MsgBox to gain control over the screen location.  In the Visual Studio environment it did exactly what I wanted.  I converted it into a class library but Strings with embedded vbCrLf characters add a blank line and lose the five spaces inserted into the line for the indent.

I've tried doubling the width of MyLabel.  The form got wider since it's predicated on MyLabel.Width but the extra line was still there.  My lines of text and the label are built as follows:

```
        'split the string on vbCrLf with some leading spaces on each line to indent the message
        strLineArr = strMsg.Split(vbCrLf)
        Dim intMaxLength As Integer = 0
        Dim intIndex As Int16 = 0
        Dim ctrLine As Int16 = 0
        strMsg = vbCrLf & vbCrLf        'put some space at the top
        For i = 0 To strLineArr.Length - 1
            If strLineArr(i).Length > intMaxLength Then
                intMaxLength = strLineArr(i).Length     'width of label is based on longest line
                intIndex = i                            'keep tack of which line
            End If
            strMsg = strMsg & Space(5) & strLineArr(i) & vbCrLf 'add five leading space for an indent
            ctrLine += 1                                'line counter for the height of the label
        Next

        'set up the label and message
        Dim lblMsg As New Label()
        lblMsg.Font = New Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
        lblMsg.Text = strLineArr(intIndex) & "cccccccccc"    'longest line; add 10 'c' spaces for margin
        Dim g As Graphics = lblMsg.CreateGraphics()
        lblMsg.Width = CInt(g.MeasureString(lblMsg.Text, lblMsg.Font).Width)
        lblMsg.Height = CInt(g.MeasureString(lblMsg.Text, lblMsg.Font).Height) * (ctrLine + 3)
        lblMsg.Text = strMsg
```

Using the string "Short Message" & vbCrLf & "Second row":

[image]

The left side is when the code is run within the Visual Studio environment; the right side is the same code executed from within the .dll.

Any thought on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just set `AutoSize` to `True` on the `Label`, assign the full `String` to its `Text` property and then resize the form based on the `Size` of the `Label`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney In the case of the string "     Short Message" & vbCrLf & "     Second Row" AuoSize is set to True and the form width is never changed from the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see a likely culprit. This is a perfect example of why you should ALWAYS have `Option Strict On`. This line:

```vb
strLineArr = strMsg.Split(vbCrLf)
```

is trying to call a method that doesn't exist. `vbCrLf` is a `String` and there is no overload of the `Split` method that accepts a `String` parameter like that. If you had `Option Strict On`, the compiler would inform you of that fact and refuse to build the project until you fixed it. With `Option Strict Off`, the compiler makes a best guess at what you want to do.

What it decides is that you actually want to call the overload that accepts a `ParamArray` of `Char` values. To accomplish that, it simply uses the first character of your `String` and discards the rest. That means that you are splitting on carriage return characters only and all but the first of the substrings you create have an erroneous line feed as the first character.

You later try to reconstruct the original text by inserting line breaks between the substrings, which means that you actually end up with one carriage return and two line feeds between each pair of substrings. I don't know why the result is different depending on where the code is but the code is wrong no matter where it is getting the expected result is just a happy accident.

Basically, your code is terrible. Sorry, but that's just the way it is. Trying to control position by adding leading spaces to each line is just terrible. You should be either using a `Label` to display the text and letting the position of the control provide the spacing from the edge of the form or else using GDI+ to draw all the text exactly where you want it. What you're doing is a filthy hack and you should stop it.

If you really must keep doing what you're doing, the correct way to split a `String` on line breaks is with a different overload of `String.Split` that actually does accept `String` delimiters rather than `Char` delimiters. Firstly, set `Option Strict On` in this project's property pages and also set it `On` in the IDE options, so it is `On` by default for future projects. You may have to fix other errors if you're using late binding or implicit conversions elsewhere. Now, if you know for a fact that your `String` will always have the default line break for the current platform, do this:

```vb
strLineArr = strMsg.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

If you don't know whether the line breaks will be Windows (CR-LF) or UNIX (LF) then you can do this:

```vb
strLineArr = strMsg.Split({ControlChars.CrLf, ControlChars.Lf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

The latter will preferentially split on the two characters together but will also split on lone line feeds.

If you really wanted to reconstruct the original text but with 5 spaces before each line, I'd suggest the following:

```vb
Dim spaces = New String(" "c, 5)

strMsg = spaces & String.Join(Environment.NewLine & spaces, strLineArr)
```

Comment: @CPRouse, if you create the `Label` in the designer then you can let the snap lines create the spacing for you. Snap lines work based on the `Padding` property of the control. You can set the property in the Properties window and then drag the control and the snap lines will create the padding. I'd suggest creating all the controls in the designer and hiding those you don't need on demand in code. You can create a `Rectangle` based on the size and location of the controls you need to show and assign that the the `ClientSize` of the form. Done.

Comment: Thank you again.  I tried the Option Strict and it didn't pick up the vbCrLf in the Split statements but I understand what you're saying.  Option Strict did pick up a dozen implicit conversions that I can fix.  I usually just use Explicit. I was anchoring the label to the top of the form, setting the BG color of the label to white and using the spaces for the indent.  My intent was to mimic the VB MsgBox but have control over the location and font.  My solution seemed simple and it worked, at least until I turned it into a library. ☺  I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @CPRouse, *"I tried the Option Strict and it didn't pick up the vbCrLf in the Split statements"*. I don't understand how that could be. I always have `Option Strict On` in the project properties - not just at the file level - and if I write `String.Empty.Split(vbCrLf)` then I get *"BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Char'"*. Are you sure you haven't turned it `On` for the project but then `Off` for that specific code file?

Comment: I have the "Option Strict On" in line 1 of the source file and I don't get that error.  I changed the lines to: "Dim strSeparator() As String = {vbCrLf}
        Dim strLineArr() As String = strMsg.Split(strSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) and that resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question you asked but it requires a bit of code so I didn't want to post it as a comment. It is basically a different way of doing things such that your current question should become moot.

In a new WinForms project, I added a new form named `MessageForm` and I added a `Label` to it. I did not change any properties of the `Label`, which means that `AutoSize` was `True` and `Location` was {0,0}. I then added the following code:

```vb
Public Class MessageForm

    Public Sub New(message As String)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        Label1.Text = message
    End Sub

    Private Sub MessageForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ClientSize = Label1.Size
    End Sub

End Class
```

I added a `TextBox` and a `Button` to my startup form and set `MultiLine` to `True` on the `TextBox`. I then added the following code:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call New MessageForm(TextBox1.Text).ShowDialog()
    End Sub

End Class
```

When I ran my project, I was able to type any text into the `TextBox`, click the `Button` and have that text displayed in the new form exactly as you would expect. You would obviously make certain adjustments to make the form look better but I don't see why you can't implement the same principle. If you want space at the top then don't put line breaks in the text. Just leave some space between the top of the `Label` and the top of the form. Etc.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this.  The form and components (1-label; up to 3-buttons are created dynamically and runs as expected with the test code and the MyMsgBox function compiled together.  It's when I put MyMsgBox in a .dll library that the problem occurs.  That's what has me scratching my head.  I'm down to adding a few lines, build the library, test it, rinse and repeat until I find where the problem is

Comment: @CPRouse, but why create the controls dynamically at all? Why not create them in the designer and then just set their `Visible` properties at run time? I believe that your code to split and rebuild the text is the issue and it is all completely unnecessary, as far as I can tell. You've created a problem by doing unnecessary work.

Comment: With the exception of colors and start position everything changes (width, height, buttons) every time the function is called.  The difference between using the designer and creating the dialog dynamically is essentially 5 Dim statements.  You were correct about the Split on vbCrLf.  It was leaving line feeds behind and inserting extra vbCrLf's as a result.  As you probably surmised, I'm new to the .Net environment and an amateur, although I did write game code for Konami during the 80's in 8088 Assembler.  My first language was FORTRAN in 1972 at UW-Milwaukee as a HS junior.